# Why can't I create a database with my main user account with PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, terminal, command-line-arguments

So I have PostgreSQL installed fine, and am trying to run the `createdb 'test'` command in the Terminal. I am on my normal user account. When trying to create the database, I am asked for a password twice, then I get the error message `createdb: error: could not connect to database template1: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "sethmarks"`. Does this mean I entered the incorrect password or that I do not have permission to create databases under this user? I am getting confused and frustrated by this and would like to know what is going on. I am entering the password I use for the OS user I am currently logged into.

I am able to create a database when I do `sudo su - postgres` and then create it when I am doing it under the `Postgres` user, but that is not  going to work with my program. Can anybody help me figure this out?
I included a picture of the terminal to show the process and what happens when attempting to create a new db. Thank you very much.

[image: error message]

Comment: `createdb` needs to connect to the database to do its thing, and your attempt to do that failed with a password error.  Look in the server's log file for a more complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the privileges that have been granted to your user account and which privileges have been granted to PUBLIC.

You can query some privileges with psql `\du` meta command for the current user.

In your case you need at least to run as superuser:

```
grant connect on database template1 to sethmarks;
```

I don't exactly why password is requested twice: this is not caused by wrong password: I have the same behaviour but I need to give the database user  password not the OS user password.

Comment: GRANT is a SQL only statement: you need to be connected to PostgreSQL to run it. Note also createdb is a executable and that there is a corresponding SQL statement 'CREATE DATABASE'. But don't expect that each SQL statement has a corresponding executable.

Comment: if you know postgres password and username try this.`createdb -h localhost -U postgres  hi` and type the password when prompt